# javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.messages?

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle, java-ee-8

I'm trying to learn JavaEE, I was creating a template and I want to use messages.properties for pages title but I keep getting this error.

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name com.linkedin.hsportscatalog.resources.messages, locale en_GB at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)`

my project structure is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I moved messages.properties to resources folder under the main folder, and I edited the faces-config.xml application tag to be like this

```
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
```

and this solved the problem